# Export multiple layers as PNG at canvas size and in actual position

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

I have a number of layers (hundreds) on a psd. I want to export each layer as a .png file, but I want each one to be the size of the canvas, but also to maintain it's current position in the psd.

At the moment I can select multiple layers and do "export as..." but then I have to manually resize each layer to be the size of the canvas. The trouble is every layer then becomes centred.

I need to maintain the position of each element as they're all varied sizes, but they are all related to an overall picture.

Ultimately it's a character builder and each layer is a part of a character. For instance there are multiple "hat" layers. Each hat however can be a different size and so is positioned slightly differently on the character. They're all positioned correctly on the PSD, but exporting ruins this positioning. I could address this in code in the final app, but it's making more work as I have to treat each hat as distinct rather than all as generic hats. Is there an easy way to do this in Photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files` and make sure to deactivate `Trim Layers`. If you need transparency use `PNG-24` as format.

Comment: Thank you. But what if I don't have this script at all in the latest Photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

The feature of exporting layers to PNG without trimming migrated from the **File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files** menu to **File > Export > Layers to Files**. Note however that's its usability is still terrible:

- It can't create new folders (will complain about destination not existing)
- It's prohibitively slow. It duplicates documents, adds and removes layers one by one and performs some other crazy actions I don't understand. It easily takes 10-20 seconds per layer.

I don't enjoy sitting in front of my screen for 10 minutes watching this script run, so I wrote a simple script:

```js
if (!Array.from) {
    Array.from = (function () {
        var toStr = Object.prototype.toString;
        var isCallable = function (fn) { return typeof fn === 'function' || toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]' };
        var toInteger = function (value) {
            var number = Number(value);
            if (isNaN(number))
                return 0;
            if (number === 0 || !isFinite(number))
                return number;
            return (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(number));
        };
        var maxSafeInteger = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;
        var toLength = function (value) { return Math.min(Math.max(toInteger(value), 0), maxSafeInteger) };
        return function from(arrayLike /*, mapFn, thisArg */) {
            var c = this;
            var items = Object(arrayLike);
            if (arrayLike == null)
                throw new TypeError("Array.from requires an array-like object - not null or undefined");
            var mapFn = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void undefined;
            var T;
            if (typeof mapFn !== 'undefined') {
                if (!isCallable(mapFn))
                    throw new TypeError("Array.from: when provided, the second argument must be a function");
                if (arguments.length > 2)
                    T = arguments[2];
            }
            var len = toLength(items.length);
            var a = isCallable(c) ? Object(new c(len)) : new Array(len);
            var k = 0;
            var kValue;
            while (k < len) {
                kValue = items[k];
                a[k] = mapFn ? (typeof T === 'undefined' ? mapFn(kValue, k) : mapFn.call(T, kValue, k)) : kValue;
                k += 1;
            }
            a.length = len;
            return a;
        };
    })();
}

if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement, fromIndex) {
        var k, o = Object(this), len = o.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0)
            return -1;
        var n = +fromIndex || 0;
        if (Math.abs(n) === Infinity)
            n = 0;
        if (n >= len)
            return -1;
        k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);
        while (k < len) {
            if (k in o && o[k] === searchElement)
                return k;
            k++;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}

if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
        if (this === void 0 || this === null)
            throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined');
        if (callback.__class__ !== 'Function')
            throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
        var o = Object(this);
        var len = o.length >>> 0;
        var t = arguments.length > 1 ? thisArg : void 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            if (i in o)
                callback.call(t, o[i], i, o);
    }
}

if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
    Array.prototype.filter = function (callback, thisArg) {
        if (this === void 0 || this === null)
            throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.filter called on null or undefined');
        if (callback.__class__ !== 'Function')
            throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
        var o = Object(this);
        var len = o.length >>> 0;
        var a = [];
        var t = arguments.length > 1 ? thisArg : void 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in o) {
                var val = o[i];
                if (callback.call(t, val, i, o))
                    a.push(val);
            }
        }
        return a;
    };
}

if (!Array.prototype.some) {
    Array.prototype.some = function (callback, thisArg) {
        if (this === void 0 || this === null)
            throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.some called on null or undefined');
        if (callback.__class__ !== 'Function')
            throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
        var o = Object(this);
        var len = o.length >>> 0;
        var t = arguments.length > 1 ? thisArg : void 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            if (i in o && callback.call(t, o[i], i, o))
                return true;
        return false;
    };
}

if (!Array.prototype.map) {
    Array.prototype.map = function (callback, thisArg) {
        if (this === void 0 || this === null)
            throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.map called on null or undefined');
        if (callback.__class__ !== 'Function')
            throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
        var o = Object(this);
        var len = o.length >>> 0;
        var t = arguments.length > 1 ? thisArg : void 0;
        var a = new Array(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            if (i in o)
                a[i] = callback.call(t, o[i], i, o);
        return a;
    };
}

if (!Array.prototype.flat) {
    Array.prototype.flat = function (depth) {
        if (this === void 0 || this === null)
            throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.flat called on null or undefined');
        depth = typeof depth === 'undefined' ? 1 : Number(depth) || 0;
        var a = [];
        var forEach = a.forEach;
        var flatDeep = function (ai, di) {
            forEach.call(ai,
                function (val) {
                    if (di > 0 && Array.isArray(val))
                        flatDeep(val, di - 1);
                    else
                        a.push(val);
                });
        };
        flatDeep(this, depth);
        return a;
    };
} 

if (!String.prototype.repeat) {
    String.prototype.repeat = function (count) {
        var input = this;
        var result = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            result += input;
        return result;
    }
}

if (!String.prototype.padStart) {
    String.prototype.padStart = function (targetLength, padString) {
        targetLength = targetLength >> 0;
        padString = String((typeof padString !== 'undefined' ? padString : ' '));
        if (this.length > targetLength)
            return String(this);
        else {
            targetLength = targetLength - this.length;
            if (targetLength > padString.length)
                padString += padString.repeat(targetLength / padString.length);
            return padString.slice(0, targetLength) + String(this);
        }
    };
}

var id = {
    name: 0,
    as: 0,
    method: 0,
    quick: 0,
    PNGInterlaceType: 0,
    PNGInterlaceNone: 0,
    PNGFilter: 0,
    PNGFilterAdaptive: 0,
    compression: 0,
    minDigits: 0,
    PNGFormat: 0,
    quality: 0,
    export_: 0,
    reverse: 0,
    animationFrameClass: 0,
    startNumber: 0,
    useDocumentSize: 0,
    useDocumentFrameRate: 0,
    allFrames: 0,
    renderAlpha: 0,
    alphaRendering: 0,
    straight: 0,
    Z3DPrefHighQualityErrorThreshold: 0,
    videoExport: 0,
    animationFramesFromLayers: 0,
    apply: 0, // "Aply"
    at: 0, // "At  "
    blendMode: 0, // "BlnM"
    blue: 0, // "Bl  "
    channel: 0, // "Chnl"
    color: 0, // "Clr "
    commandID: 0,
    delete_: 0, // "Dlt "
    directory: 0,
    enabled: 0, // "enab"
    frameFill: 0, // "FrFl"
    frameFX: 0, // "FrFX"
    frameStyle: 0, // "FStl"
    green: 0, // "Grn "
    invokeCommand: 0,
    kcanDispatchWhileModal: 0,
    layer: 0, // "Lyr "
    layerEffects: 0, // "Lefx"
    layerStyle: 0,
    level: 0, // "Lvl "
    make: 0, // "Mk  "
    makeFrameAnimation: 0,
    mask: 0, // "Msk "
    mode: 0, // "Md  "
    new_: 0, // "Nw  "
    normal: 0, // "Nrml"
    opacity: 0, // "Opct"
    ordinal: 0, // "Ordn"
    outsetFrame: 0, // "OutF"
    overprint: 0,
    paintType: 0, // "PntT"
    percentUnit: 0, // "#Prc"
    pixelsUnit: 0, // "#Pxl"
    PNGMethod: 0,
    present: 0,
    property: 0, // "Prpr"
    rasterizeItem: 0,
    rasterizeLayer: 0,
    red: 0, // "Rd  "
    RGBColor: 0, // "RGBC"
    scale: 0, // "Scl "
    sequenceRenderSettings: 0,
    set: 0, // "setd"
    showInDialog: 0,
    size: 0, // "Sz  "
    solidColor: 0, // "SClr"
    solidFill: 0, // "SoFi"
    style: 0, // "Styl"
    subdirectory: 0,
    target: 0, // "null"
    targetEnum: 0, // "Trgt"
    thresholdClassEvent: 0, // "Thrs"
    to: 0, // "T   "
    transparency: 0,
    userMaskEnabled: 0,
    using: 0, // "Usng"
    what: 0 // "What"
};

function setupPhotoshopIdentifiers() {
    for (var kid in id)
        id[kid] = stringIDToTypeID(kid.replace("_", ""));
    var classesWithPutMethods = {
        ActionDescriptor: {
            2: ['Boolean', 'Class', 'Double', 'Integer', 'LargeInteger', 'List', 'Path', 'Reference', 'String'],
            3: ['Enumerated', 'Object', 'UnitDouble']
        },
        ActionReference: {
            1: ['Class'],
            2: ['Identifier', 'Index', 'Name', 'Offset', 'Property'],
            3: ['Enumerated']
        }
    };
    var chainMethods = {
        1: function (f) {
            return function (a0) {
                this[f](a0);
                return this;
            };
        },
        2: function (f) {
            return function (a0, a1) {
                this[f](a0, a1);
                return this;
            };
        },
        3: function (f) {
            return function (a0, a1, a2) {
                this[f](a0, a1, a2);
                return this;
            };
        }
    }
    for (var className in classesWithPutMethods) {
        for (var argCount in classesWithPutMethods[className]) {
            for (var iMethod in classesWithPutMethods[className][argCount]) {
                var method = classesWithPutMethods[className][argCount][iMethod];
                this[className].prototype['set' + method] = chainMethods[argCount]('put' + method);
            }
        }
    }
}

function desc() {
    return new ActionDescriptor();
}

function ref() {
    return new ActionReference();
}

function execute(command, action) {
    executeAction(command, action || desc(), DialogModes.NO);
}

setupPhotoshopIdentifiers();

var folderPostfix = "-layers";

function savePng(path) {
    var opts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
    opts.PNG8 = false;
    opts.transparency = true;
    opts.interlaced = false;
    opts.quality = 100;
    doc.exportDocument(new File(path), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, opts);
}

function makeFrameAnimation() {
    execute(id.makeFrameAnimation);
}

function animationFramesFromLayers() {
    execute(id.animationFramesFromLayers);
}

function reverseFrames() {
    execute(id.reverse, desc()
        .setReference(id.target, ref()
            .setEnumerated(id.animationFrameClass, id.ordinal, id.targetEnum)));
}

function renderVideo(opts) {
    var pngFormat = desc()
        .setEnumerated(id.method, id.PNGMethod, id.quick)
        .setEnumerated(id.PNGInterlaceType, id.PNGInterlaceType, id.PNGInterlaceNone)
        .setEnumerated(id.PNGFilter, id.PNGFilter, id.PNGFilterAdaptive)
        .setInteger(id.compression, 6);
    var videoExport = desc()
        .setObject(id.sequenceRenderSettings, id.sequenceRenderSettings,
            desc().setObject(id.as, id.PNGFormat, pngFormat))
        .setPath(id.directory, new File(opts.directory))
        //.setString(id.subdirectory, opts.subdirectory)
        .setString(id.name, ".png")
        .setInteger(id.minDigits, 1)
        .setInteger(id.startNumber, 0)
        .setBoolean(id.useDocumentSize, true)
        .setBoolean(id.useDocumentFrameRate, true)
        .setBoolean(id.allFrames, true)
        .setEnumerated(id.renderAlpha, id.alphaRendering, id.straight)
        .setInteger(id.quality, 1)
        .setInteger(id.Z3DPrefHighQualityErrorThreshold, 5);
    execute(id.export_, desc()
        .setObject(id.using, id.videoExport, videoExport));
}

function getArtLayers(doc) {
    return Array.from(doc.artLayers);
}

function main() {
    // Prepare output folder
    var outFolder = new Folder(doc.path + "/" + doc.name.replace(".psd", folderPostfix));
    if (!outFolder.exists)
        outFolder.create();

    // Copy visible layers into new document
    var docCopy = app.activeDocument = doc.duplicate();
    try {
        getArtLayers(docCopy)
            .filter(function(layer) { return !layer.visible })
            .forEach(function(layer) { layer.remove() });

        // Generate file names from layer names
        var layerIndexLength = (docCopy.artLayers.length - 1 + "").length;
        var formatLayerFileName = function(layer, iLayer) { return (iLayer + "").padStart(layerIndexLength, "0") + " " + layer.name };
        var getOutPath = function(name) { return outFolder.fullName + "/" + name + ".png" };
        var layerFileNames = getArtLayers(docCopy).map(formatLayerFileName).map(getOutPath);

        // Confirm replacing existing files
        var existingFiles = layerFileNames.filter(function(fileName) { return new File(fileName).exists });
        if (existingFiles.length > 0 && !confirm(existingFiles.length + " files already exist in the target folder. Replace?"))
            return;

        // Export layers as video frames
        makeFrameAnimation();
        animationFramesFromLayers();
        reverseFrames();
        renderVideo({ directory: outFolder.fullName });

        // Rename sequental file names to proper layer names
        layerFileNames
            .forEach(function(fileName, iLayer) {
                new File(fileName).remove();
                new File(getOutPath(iLayer)).rename(fileName);
            });
    } finally {
        // Close document copy without saving
        docCopy.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
        app.activeDocument = doc;
    }

    alert("Layers exported.");
}

var doc = app.activeDocument;
//doc.suspendHistory('Athari - Export Layers', 'main()');
main();
```

It doesn't provide a fancy user interface and probably fails in many cases, but it gets the job done 5 times faster. Feel free to adapt it to your needs.

**Update**
Based on suggestion from **@joojaa**, replaced export to PNG with export to PNG video frames. Now it's 5 times faster than before (3 layers per second in my case), doesn't create an entry in the undo history and even shows a progress bar. (I copy-pasted my includes right into the script, so it may look very long, but the actual code is just one page at the very end.)

Comment: Its actually faster to convert layers to frames and save the animation. As a bonus it is possible to do directly from the user interface.

Comment: @joojaa Do you mean **TImeline > Create Frame Animation** + **Timeline > Make Frame From Layers** + **File > Export > Render Video**? If it's considerably faster, a script can fix file names and will make toggling Timeline panel unnecessary. I'll try it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @joojaa Updated the script. Export to video is so much faster! 100 layers in 30 seconds.